# Item-level permissions on document library

Tags: document-library, permissions, list-item, development

I ultimately want to grant users edit permission only on the items they created.

According to this article:

http://www.hersheytech.com/Blog/SharePoint/tabid/197/entryid/28/Default.aspx

I can do that by assigning ReadSecurity and WriteSecurity certain values. It works - the problem is, my document library has sub folders - and they are all hidden when assigning the relevant values (2) for both fields.

This then pushes me in the direction of breaking role inheritance and assigning permissions to each specific document on upload. Although this is achievable since I'm using a custom document upload control, I preferably want to avoid it as I appreciate it will, or at least *can*, have repercussions with regards to performance and potentially unnecessary complexities of the way the whole permissions is structured.

My question - is there a way around the problem I mentioned with the first approach? Or should I just opt for the 2nd? Bearing in mind there will be many documents uploaded to this system, all of which will be searched.

Comment: Hi DeeMac,

I do not realy get the problem you try to explain.
Having subfolders should not change the functionality of Write & ReadSecurity, no?

Could you maybe explain abit more what kind of problem you are facing. Why would you want to go for item level permissions?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm assuming the folders are hidden from the user once I've applied these security settings as the folders were not created by them?

Comment: But isn't that what you want. Or is it that you want the users to be able to upload documents to these folders which haven't been created by them.

Comment: Basically, users (without full permissions already assigned to the document library list) should be able to only edit the documents they uploaded. All other documents, however, should be viewable regardless of whether they uploaded them or not.

Comment: Then I guess ReadSecurity = 1 and WriteSecurity = 2 should work??

Comment: The only issue I can think of is what Nadeem is saying... Users will not see the folders, since they are not created by them. So they can not upload items in the folder... I'm not sure tho, since I have no idea whether that Read/WriteSecurity is affecting the folders or not.

Is this the issue your facing?

Answer (score 3):

This is why you shouldn't use Folders in SharePoint, change your folder structure to a MetaData tree and you won't have this issue.

Comment: +1 I agree with Hugh. Plus, the ReadSecurity/WriteSecurity is bypassed with "Open with Explorer" so that's not a truly secure option.